# Using Compress-Archive to compress multiple folders multithreadded with Powershell

Tags: multithreading, powershell, jobs, compress-archive

Everyday I need create archives of the following

```
C:.
└───1.Jan
    ├───20000
    │       img1.bmp
    │       img2.bmp
    │       img3.bmp
    │
    ├───20001
    │       img1.bmp
    │       img2.bmp
    │       img3.bmp
    │
    ├───20002
    │       img1.bmp
    │       img2.bmp
    │       img3.bmp
    │
    ├───20003
    │       img1.bmp
    │       img2.bmp
    │       img3.bmp
    │
    ├───20004
    │       img1.bmp
    │       img2.bmp
    │       img3.bmp
    │
    ├───20005
    │        img1.bmp
    │        img2.bmp
    │        img3.bmp
    │
    └───Entered
```

I currently have the script working with creating the zip files one at a time, However I can sometimes have 200+ folders to zip and they are different sizes so I would like to get this working multithreadded.

```
function Zip-Folders([String] $FolderPath) {
if ($FolderPath -eq '') {
    return
} 
else {
    $FolderNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Name -Directory -Exclude Enter*
        foreach ($i in $FolderNames) {
            $TempPath = "$FolderPath\$i"
            $TempFileName = "$i Photos"
            if (-Not(Get-ChildItem -Path $TempPath | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*.zip'})) {
                Write-Host "[$TempPath] has been compressed to [$TempFileName]."
                Compress-Archive -Path $tempPath\* -DestinationPath $tempPath\$TempFileName
            }
            Else {
                Write-Host "[$i] has already been compressed."
            }
        }
}
}
```

The code asks for the folder via a Folderbrowser dialog.

If someone could either help with the code or point me in the direction where I can find the information for this, I am a beginner with PowerShell but have done some programming.

If there is any other information needed let me know.

Comment: If you have the ability to install modules, such as [ThreadJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/?view=powershell-7.1) this is quite easy to do. Another option is to use Runspace however this would require more coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it using [`Runspace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0), use the `-Threshold` parameter depending on how many folders you want to compress at the same time.

As commented, it is highly recommended to use the [`ThreadJob` Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1) if you have the ability to install Modules in your environment.

```bash
function Zip-Folders {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ -PathType Container })]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String] $FolderPath,

        [int] $Threshold = 10
    )

    begin {
        $RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $Threshold)
        $RunspacePool.Open()
        $subFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Directory -Exclude Enter*
    }
    
    process {
        try {
            $runspaces = foreach ($folder in $subFolders) {
                $instance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
                    param($thisFolder)

                    $fileName = "{0} Photos.zip" -f $thisFolder.Name
                    $absolutePath = $thisFolder.FullName
                    $zipPath = Join-Path $absolutePath -ChildPath $fileName

                    if(-not (Get-ChildItem -Path $absolutePath -Filter *.zip)) {
                        Compress-Archive -Path $absolutePath\* -DestinationPath $zipPath
                        return "[$absolutePath] has been compressed to [$zipPath]."
                    }

                    "[$absolutePath] has already been compressed."
                }).AddParameter('thisFolder', $folder)

                $instance.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Instance = $instance
                    Handle   = $instance.BeginInvoke()
                }
            }

            foreach($r in $runspaces) {
                $r.Instance.EndInvoke($r.Handle)
                $r.Instance.ForEach('Dispose')
            }
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
        }
        finally {
            $runspaces.ForEach('Clear')
            $RunspacePool.ForEach('Dispose')
        }
    }
}
```